# Add instances of the Button to the form dynamically in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I use MonoDevelop 2.4.2.1 on WinXP.
I have a window with VBox and button 'MyButton'. Now I should write a method for 'MyButton' for creating other Button's instances dinamically. I can't understand how to handle containers and widgets.
Please give me advice how to do this.

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do something like:

```
myButton.Clicked += delegate {
    var nextButton = new Button ("Hello");
    box.PackEnd (nextButton, false, false, 0);
};
```

You can find GTK# tutorials at http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpTutorials and at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtksharptutorial/

In particular, I would suggest you read http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Widget_Layout_and_Packing

Comment: Thank you very much for example! I've found everything I need.